# Design time data in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, expression-blend, design-time

[using vs2010 & expression blend v4]

Hi - trying to load up some design time data in WPF and Blend, using Josh Smith's concept here: http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/assembly-level-initialization-at-design-time/
e.g.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
public class DesignTimeBootstrapperAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DesignTimeBootstrapperAttribute(Type type)
    {
        var dep = new DependencyObject();
        Debug.WriteLine("here..?");
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(dep))
        {
            // TODO: Design-time initialization…
            IBootstrapper instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IBootstrapper;
            if (instance != null)
            {
                instance.Run();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With my attribute here in AssemblyInfo.cs, where AppBootstrapper extends MefBootstrapper.

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2010")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: DesignTimeBootstrapper(typeof(AppBootstrapper))]
```

I don't want to use the Blend sample data, a) as it doesn't seem to create data for ObservableCollection and b) I'm in design mode by definition, so things will change quite a lot, but my 'generated data' will not.

Anyway, nothing seems to be happening.

Q1: How is it possible to debug the design time initialisation of my bootstrapper?
Q2: Do I need additional blend namespaces/ attributes etc in my View XAML?

(In my bootstrapper I'm just registering a different module where I want to replace RunTimeService with a DesignTimeService, exporting the IService interface).

TIA

Comment: Have you succeeded in making this chunk of code work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To debug this:

- Open your project in VS2010
- Set a breakpoint in the assembly attribute constructor
- Start a new instance of Blend 4
- From VS2010 use Debug -> Attach to Process: and choose Blend
- Switch to Blend and open your project
- Open a XAML file that references your sample data

Also, any `Debug.WriteLine` should appear in the VS2010 output window.

If you can't get the attribute method to work (I haven't tried it myself), you can use this method (which I have used) from [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/):

```
private bool? _isInDesignMode;

public bool IsInDesignMode
{
    get
    {
        if (!_isInDesignMode.HasValue)
        {
            var prop = DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty;
            _isInDesignMode =
                (bool)DependencyPropertyDescriptor
                .FromProperty(prop, typeof(FrameworkElement))
                .Metadata.DefaultValue;
        }

        return _isInDesignMode.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: So in your ViewModel do you check whether it's true and then return your fake data from a VM property, like an ObservableCollection? The problem I could see then would be wiring up the ViewModel and the View as I'm using MEF and Prism. I'll have a look at the way you said to wire up vs2010 and blend then maybe I can get that working. Thanks.